# What is a good book to buy on php cms development?

Tags: php, zend-framework, content-management-system

I would like to build a cms with php using zend framework.  I have been disappointed in the past when purchasing programming books only for the author to say, "well this example would not really work well in production." I would like to know if anyone has a recommendation for a book on building a production level cms using php. I prefer zend framework but if you know of a helpful book I am flexible with the frameworks I plan to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend [Zend Framework in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988320).

It will guide you through developing a real project using Zend Framework.